# C# and override operator with ref

Tags: c#, overriding, operator-keyword, ref

Look at this code:

```
public class classA
{
    public string something;
    public classA()
    {
        something = "aaa";
    }
}

public class classB
{
    private classA someA = new classA();

    public static implicit operator classA(classB val)
    {
       val.someA.something = "From B";
       return val.someA;
    }

}
```

ClassB contains ClassA, as simplified case.
There is a method (function, call it as you like) that receive ClassA as param:

```
public void test( classA var)
{
    MessageBox.Show(var.something);
}
```

and another method that receive ClassA as a ref parameter:

```
public void testByRef( ref classA var)
{
    MessageBox.Show(var.something);
}
```

Now, I have overridden operator ClassA in ClassB so first function can be called with ClassB as well, but I do not know how to override ref operator in ClassB for second call:

```
    classA a = new classA();
    classB b = new classB();

    test(a);    // Works
    test(b);    // Works

    testByRef(ref a);    // Works
    testByRef(ref b);    // Does not work - error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref classB' to 'ref classA'
```

I have tried overloading like this

```
public static implicit operator ref classA(classB val)
{
   val.someA.something = "From B";
   return val.someA;
}
```

and variations but with no success.

Has anyone encounter this problem and have solution ?

Thanks,
Sasa Kajic

Comment: A reference to the return value of `b`'s `operator classA(classB val)` is in no sense a reference to `b`. Pretending it is would simply cause confusion, because the method you're passing it to would be altering a temporary value that will vanish when the method returns. Then you'd be here asking if we had a solution to *that* problem. It's no good to anybody if something that looks like `f(ref b)` is in fact `f(lolwut)`

Comment: As yoo can see, someA in ClassB is not temporary and will never be.

Comment: I need ref from B as I want it to be changed and still be part of B, so separate 'afromb' is not solution.

Comment: It's temporary because you are implicitly converting from one to another, you cannot reference it because it no longer exists in that form.

Comment: As you should be able to infer, the C# design team doesn't think it's the compiler's job to analyze the operator and figure that out for you.

Comment: OK, `testByRef(ref b.someA )`.

Comment: The language doesn't do what you want. If you share what you're actually trying to accomplish with this nonexistent feature, we can help you do it using features that the language actually has. C# is a pretty versatile language. Some even say it's Turing complete. It's unlikely that you've found something it can't do.

Comment: Usage is very simple, client connected can have several 'states', eg: "connecting", "working", "idling", etc... Those states are all separate classes with respective methods(functions) and variables. They are all part of one class (ClassB in this sample) as it is easier to pass only one object around, and function called will decide what to do (and who else to call) in each 'state' case.

Comment: I know I can use 'testByRef(ref b.someA )' but that will require of 'caller' to know inside workings of class which he has no need to. All he needs to know is that this function will change the param passed as it sees fit in that moment and base on param 'state'.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a variable of *exactly* type `ClassA` if you want to pass it by reference.  The current value of that variable can be an instance of `ClassB`, but the type of the *variable* needs to be `ClassA`.

```
classA a = new classA();
classA b = new classB();

testByRef(ref b);
```

That will compile.  This needs to happen since `testByRef` could assign a value to `var`, and that value could be anything of type `ClassA`, and it may not be a `ClassB` instance, so you can't provide a variable of type `ClassB`.

The implicit conversion operator will always return a *value*.  It cannot return a *variable*, which is what you're trying to do with `ref` in that operator.  There is no way to support this.

It's also worth noting that your `testByRef` method doesn't actually mutate the variable `var`, so there's no reason to actually pass it by reference.

Finally, you *really* shouldn't be doing what you're doing in your original implicit operator implementation by mutating the operand that is passed in.  That's *extremely* confusing to users; an implicit operator should create a new instance of the type you're converting to *without changing the original object in any way*.

Comment: testbyref is just that, test functions. Real function is changing it.

Comment: and ClassB is passed to my 'calling test' functions by reference so I can not change it to ClassA.

Comment: and ClassB is designed that way so it 'changes' depending on the state application is at that moment, so it can be "working", or "connecting" or "transmitting" or "whatever", with appropriate info and such.

Comment: @Kajko One approach you might try is to find out what design pattern people usually use for whatever you're doing, and implement it conventionally.

Comment: @Kajko So it sounds like you want to be mutating the object, rather than mutating a variable, so that the state of the *one* object instance changes.  If you just want to be creating new objects with a new state, you should probably just be returning them; the caller can then assign it to the same variable it passed in if it wants, or it can do whatever else it wants instead.

Comment: @Servy It is working right now just as you described, but I do not have a 'history', just current state. Just example of top of my head: client download, got cut off, connect again and resume download. With the way it works right now, he will have to start download from beginning not resume. With new approach I always have client and 'history', I know previous state and such.

Comment: @Kajko If you want the class to store its history, you can have it keep track of it's previous states whenever you mutate it.  You don't need any of this to do that.